# Eigenvector normalization in numpy

Tags: numpy, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I'm using the linalg in numpy to compute eigenvalues and eigenvectors of matrices of signed reals. 
I've read [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18708642/unexpected-eigenvectors-in-numpy) but still don't grasp the normalization of eigenvectors.
Here is an example straight off [Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors)

```
    import numpy as np
    from numpy import linalg as la

    a = np.matrix([[2, 1], [1, 2]], dtype=np.float)

    eigh_vals, eigh_vects = np.linalg.eig(a)

    print 'eigen_values='
    print eigh_vals

    print 'eigen_vectors='
    print eigh_vects
```

The eigenvalues are 1 and 3.
For eigenvectors we expect scalar multiples of [1, -1] and [1, 1], which I get:

```
    eig_vals=
    [ 3.  1.]
    eig_vets=
    [[ 0.70710678 -0.70710678]
    [ 0.70710678  0.70710678]]
```

I understand the 1/sqrt(2) factor is to have the norm=1 but why? 
Can normalization be 'switched off'?
Thanks!

Comment: What should be the result if it is switched off? Otherwise `eig_vets.dot(eig_vals).dot(eig_vets.conj().T)` won't give you the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

The key message for the first eigenvector in the Wikipedia article is

> Any non-zero vector with v1 = −v2 solves this equation.

So the actual solution is `V1 = [x, -x]`. Picking the vector `V1 = [1, -1]` may be pleasing to the human eye, but it is just as aritrary as picking a vector `V1 = [104051, -104051]` or any other real value.

Actually, picking `V1 = [1, -1] / sqrt(2)` is *the least arbitrary*. Of all the possible vectors for `V1`, it's the only one that is of unit length.

However if instead of unit length you prefer the first value to be `1`, you can do

```
eigh_vects /= eigh_vects[:, 0]
```

Comment: I like this answer better since it explains the rational behind why normalization takes place, and the explaination of how eigen vectors are chosen. Additionally answering the question with a reasonable  strategy to un-normalize that I have opted to use.

This answer also remains in the "numpy" world without installing yet another package.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
v = sp.Matrix([[2, 1], [1, 2]])
v_vec  = v.eigenvects()
```

v_vec is a list contains 2 tuples:

```
[(1, 1, [Matrix([
   [-1],
   [ 1]])]), (3, 1, [Matrix([
   [1],
   [1]])])]
```

1 and 3 is the two eigenvalues. The '1' behind 1 & 3 is the number of the eigenvalues. In each tuple, the third element is the eigenvector of each eigenvalue. It is a Matrix object in sp. You can convert a Matrix object to the np array.

```
v_vec1 = np.array(v_vec[0][2], dtype=float)
v_vec2 = np.array(v_vec[1][2], dtype=float)
print('v_vec1 =', v_vec1)
print('v_vec2 =', v_vec2)
```

Here is the normalized eigenvectors you would get:

```
v_vec1 = [[-1.  1.]]
v_vec2 = [[1. 1.]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If `sympy` is an option for you, it appears to normalize less aggressively:

```
import sympy
a = sympy.Matrix([[2, 1], [1, 2]])
a.eigenvects()
# [(1, 1, [Matrix([
# [-1],
# [ 1]])]), (3, 1, [Matrix([
# [1],
# [1]])])]
```